# Edit requiredResourceAccess of Azure AD Application using MVC or C#.NET application

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am running **PowerShell** code from **C#** app to register an application in Azure AD (create an application in Azure AD).I want to Add and Grant permissions for "**Power BI Service**" and "**Windows Azure Active Directory**" on this registered application.

I found that we can also edit the `Manifest` of Azure AD application and pass `requiredResourceAccess` array. This will automatically add and grant permission for the application.

Please help me with PowerShell commands which can be run using C# code or C# code to **edit `Manifest`** of application so that add grant and permissions to Azure Ad Application programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the powershell command below, in the sample, it grants the some permissions of `Windows Azure Active Directory` api and `Power BI Service` api.

```
$req = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$acc1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6","Scope"
$acc2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "aaff0dfd-0295-48b6-a5cc-9f465bc87928","Role"
$req.ResourceAccess = $acc1,$acc2
$req.ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

$reqe = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$acc1e = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "ddb3ca45-a192-477d-acb2-46bf9dc586de","Scope"
$acc2e = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "28379fa9-8596-4fd9-869e-cb60a93b5d84","Role"
$reqe.ResourceAccess = $acc1e,$acc2e
$reqe.ResourceAppId = "00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <ObjectId> -RequiredResourceAccess @($req,$reqe)
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the guids from? (both the `ResourceAppId` and permission guid.