# AcquireTokenAsyn in Azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to make some graph API calls from AZure CloudShell. To make the API call I have to acquire a token. I have a 100% working code in Azure Desktop version (PSVersion 5.1)
But same code not working in CloudShell, which runs s with (Core - 6.2)

Cloudshell libraries have couple of mismatches with documentations

Im trying to use this version of [AcuireTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Uri_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_IPlatformParameters_).

For which I have to initial PlatmforParameter
but when Im getting an error

> $platformParameters = New-Object
>   "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters"
>   "Auto" New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PlatformParameters"
>   and the argument count: "1". At line:1 char:23
>   + ... arameters = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirecto ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Seems PlatformParameters accepting no arg constructor

This is my working code in Powershell Desktop 5.1 version

```
    $clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"  # well-known client ID for AzurePowerShell
    $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" # redirect URI for Azure PowerShell

    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.windows.net"
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $platformParameters = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters" -ArgumentList 'Auto'
    $authResultTask = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, $platformParameters)
    $authResultTask.Wait()
    $authResult = $authResultTask.Result
```

But same code doesn't work in CloudShell

Is there any well known variation of acquiring token from Azure Cloud shell

Comment: May I know which graph APIs do you want to call? And why do you want to do them in the cloud shell?

Comment: I'm Trying to call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http 

I am able to create an app using New-AzureRmADApplication cmdlet
but need to configure the created app (ex: Assign API permissions, roles etc...)

Comment: No need to to do that, there is a bulit-in command [`Set-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) in `AzureAD` module. But I want to know why you want to do that in the cloud shell?

Comment: I wanted to automate the application creation and configuration via powershell script

Comment: @JoyWang any idea on the problem I'm explaining about constructor mismatches (eg: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters)

Comment: Why don't you use `AzureAD` module? Most things related to Azure AD can be accessed. And you still not tell me why you insist on using cloud shell instead of window powershell in local?

Comment: I already given the reason - "I wanted to automate the application creation and configuration via powershell script" because it is a frequent thing I'm planning to do

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to automate the application creation and configuration via powershell script

As mentioned in the comment, no need to call the MS Graph APIs manually, you can automate them via [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) powershell module, which is also available in the cloud shell.

**Samples:**

1.*Create application* - [`New-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0)

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "My new application"  -IdentifierUris "http://mynewapp.contoso.com"
```

2.*Update an application* - [`Set-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0)

For example, set the API permissions for the application.

```
$req = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$acc1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6","Scope"
$acc2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "aaff0dfd-0295-48b6-a5cc-9f465bc87928","Role"
$req.ResourceAccess = $acc1,$acc2
$req.ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

$reqe = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$acc1e = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "ddb3ca45-a192-477d-acb2-46bf9dc586de","Scope"
$acc2e = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "28379fa9-8596-4fd9-869e-cb60a93b5d84","Role"
$reqe.ResourceAccess = $acc1e,$acc2e
$reqe.ResourceAppId = "00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <ObjectId> -RequiredResourceAccess @($req,$reqe)
```

I test the script in local and cloud shell, both work fine. If you have other requirements, just look into the [Azure AD PowerShell doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0), you can do most things related to AAD via this module.

For more details about the sample, you could refer to the two links, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164581/how-to-configure-a-new-azure-ad-application-through-powershell) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911829/edit-requiredresourceaccess-of-azure-ad-application-using-mvc-or-c-net-applicat/53915337#53915337).

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang 
I will verify the code and will update the comment section